# Ping timeout issues

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, timeout, ping

Good afternoon,

I'm working on a three computers (under Linux Mint 14) LAN. They are connected to a switch and none of them have any firewall. 
The problem is that each one of them is really slow to detect failures of one of their peers.

For example, I proceed to that test :
I ping from 192.168.0.2 to 192.168.0.3. After 10 seconds, I unplung 192.168.0.3 from the switch... the problem is that 192.168.0.2 takes 48 seconds to detect that !
Here you'll finds logs of that test

```
oneadmin@192.168.0.2 ~ $ ping -v -i 1 192.168.0.3
PING 192.168.0.3 (192.168.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.236 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=4 ttl=64 time=0.229 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=5 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=6 ttl=64 time=0.210 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=7 ttl=64 time=0.271 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=8 ttl=64 time=0.273 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=9 ttl=64 time=0.291 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.3: icmp_req=10 ttl=64 time=0.201 ms
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=58 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=59 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=60 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=61 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=62 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=63 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=64 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=65 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=66 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=67 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=68 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.2 icmp_seq=69 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What shall I do to reduce that time?

Best regards,
Sonsolès

Comment: Note : the problem is still here with "-W" option in ping.

Answer (score 2):

You can use -w to specify timeout

```
ping -c1  -w1 192.168.0.3
```

**Options Details:**

```
-c count

                  Stop  after  sending  count  ECHO_REQUEST packets. With deadline option, ping
                  waits for count ECHO_REPLY packets, until the timeout expires.


-w deadline
                      Specify a timeout, in seconds, before ping exits regardless of how many pack‐
                      ets  have  been sent or received. In this case ping does not stop after count
                      packet are sent, it waits either for deadline expire or  until  count  probes
                      are answered or for some error notification from network.
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can you `-O`

```
ping -O host.com
```

> claudionei@TI-03 ~ $ ping -O 10.251.15.251
> PING 10.251.15.251 (10.251.15.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=4.50 ms
> no answer yet for icmp_seq=2
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=1950 ms
> no answer yet for icmp_seq=3
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=3 ttl=62 time=1409 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=4 ttl=62 time=576 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=5 ttl=62 time=654 ms
> 64 bytes from 10.251.15.251: icmp_seq=6 ttl=62 time=4.41 ms
>
> --- 10.251.15.251 ping statistics ---
> 6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5001ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.416/766.491/1950.291/710.053 ms, pipe 2